# Simple cellular homology calculation

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a CW complex and let $X^{n}$ denote the $n$-skeleton of $X$.  Is it true that $H_{k}(X,X^{n+1})=0$ for $k\leq n+1$?  How can I see this using similar calculations that I am familiar with, such as $H_{k}(X^{n},X^{n-1})=0$ if $k\neq n$, and $H_{k}(X^{n})=0$ for $k>n$.  I can show this for $k<n+1$ using the long exact sequence of the pair $(X,X^{n+1})$, but I am stumped on the $k=n+1$ case.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\wt{\widetilde}$
The short answer is that $(X,X^{n+1})$ is a good pair (in the sense of Hatcher), so $H_k(X,X^{n+1})\cong H_k(X/X^{n+1})$ and $X/X^{n+1}$ only has cells in dimension $\ge n+2$, so only has non-trivial homology in dimension $\ge n+2$.

Alternatively, one can look at the LES of the triple $(X^n,X^{n+1},X)$ which includes the exact sequence
$$\widetilde H_k(X^{n+1},X^n)\to\widetilde H_k(X,X^n)\to\widetilde H_k(X,X^{n+1}).$$
We induct (in $n$) downwards from $\dim X$ (in particular, we're assuming $\dim X<\infty$ here). We know the LHS vanishes for $k\le n$ and the RHS vanishes for $k\le n+1$, so the middle term vanishes for $k\le n$.

Finally, maybe the approach that best answers your question is this one. One consequence of cellular homology equalling singular homology is that $\wt H_k(X)\cong\wt H_k(X^n)$ when $n\ge k+1$. Using this, one can compare the long exact sequences of the pairs $(X,X^n)$ and $(X^{n+1},X^n)$ to see that $\wt H_k(X,X^n)\cong\wt H_k(X^{n+1},X^n)$ for $k\le n$, which gives the vanishing result you are after. There is a natural morphism between these long exact sequences
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\wt H_k(X^n) @>>> \wt H_k(X^{n+1}) @>>> \wt H_k(X^{n+1}, X^n) @>>> \wt H_{k-1}(X^n) @>>> \wt H_{k-1}(X^{n+1})\\
@VV\sim V @VV\sim V @VVV @VV\sim V @VV\sim V\\
\wt H_k(X^n) @>>> \wt H_k(X) @>>> \wt H_k(X, X^n) @>>> \wt H_{k-1}(X^n) @>>> \wt H_{k-1}(X)
\end{CD}$$
The vertical maps marked $\sim$ are isomorphisms when $k\le n$, so the remaining map is also an isomorphism in this range.